# tcpdump displaying no output

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump

I'm currently learning tcpdump and having trouble understanding it. When I type:

`sudo tcpdump`

It has all traffic going in and out of my machine. How would I apply this to listening to everything on my own, or another network (i.e. specifying an IP)?

I tried `sudo tcpdump host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` but there was no output.

Also, if I wanted to listen to traffic going in and out of a website, how would I do this?

I tried `sudo tcpdump -n dst host gmail.com`, but again, there was no output.

Thanks!

Comment: What you're asking for is not possible. You can't just remote into `gmail.com` and look at their traffic - that would be *terrifying*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, a host can only receive:

- any traffic sent specifically to it (*unicast*)
- any *broadcast* traffic within the specific network segement it's connected to
- any *multicast* traffic available within the network segment that it has specifically requested to receive

To receive **all** the traffic in *a network segment you own*, you would need a manageable network switch that can be configured to send a copy of all traffic to a particular switch port to which the tcpdumping system is connected.

There are some technical limitations: for example, if the total traffic in the network segment is more than a single switch port can handle, then obviously the tcpdumping system cannot receive all the traffic unless it uses multiple ports in parallel (probably in a bonding/teaming configuration).

As an alternative, you might perform a switch MAC table spoofing attack to make the switch lose track of what is connected into which port, and so make it start sending everything as broadcast. But that would be an active attack, not just passive listening.

Modern manageable switches can have anti-MAC-spoofing features: if you attempt a MAC spoofing attack against such a switch, it might just shut down your port entirely and/or alert the network administrator. In other words, doing this at work would probably be a quick way to lose your job.

Listening to all the traffic *between your computer and gmail.com* is just `sudo tcpdump -s0 -nvv host gmail.com`, but trying to listen to absolutely all traffic going into gmail.com is going to be futile: gmail.com is a geographically-distributed site with several instances all over the world. Each user normally gets connected to an instance that is reasonably close to them, network-wise.

Even if you could attack the Internet routing protocols and make the rest of the world believe that your own network is where gmail.com is located (effectively bringing the traffic of gmail.com to you), the amount of traffic would probably overload not only your own network connection, but your network provider's local equipment too.